# What is the most efficient data-structure to store planet elevation?

Tags: map-making, worldbuilding-resources

Planet elevation maps can be quite big, zooming in/out can be quite costly.

I wonder if there is a ***most efficient*** data-structure used to store elevation maps such as quad-trees or any tree-based structure that will make appear details of the planet surface only when a certain level of details is required (and not before) with a fast access to the data.

Comment: We could do with a little more information here, I've leaned more towards file storage. If you're looking for an in memory data structure some sort of tree has got to be the way to go...

Comment: While the question itself may be valid, I don't see how it relates to *worldbuilding* and have voted to close it as off topic for that reason. While [software recommendation questions may be on topic](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/23/29), this question is not one I would expect a worldbuilding expert to be able to answer. I imagine it might be on topic on [programmers.se] however, since it is about the "white board" design stage of software development.

Comment: Discussion about specific algorithms or data-structures for programming a World building software seems to be valid to me. Getting rid of this kind of questions will reduce drastically the scope of this site.

Comment: The matter is who can be expected to be able to provide a solid answer. While an answer to your question would have an *application* in creating software which can be used in worldbuilding, that doesn't make the question on topic and answerable by a *worldbuilding expert*. If you feel this sort of questions should be on topic, I would strongly suggest that you bring it up on [meta] and make your case there. (Note: the question isn't *bad* only because it's off topic *on this site*, it's just off topic.) However, I feel there are better, established sites to cater to this type of question.

Comment: I say that since software recommendations [*are* on-topic](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/23/2072), this question should be reopened, despite what @MichaelKjörling wrote above. If you agree, and have 500+ rep, vote to reopen!

Comment: @Shokhet I posted a [meta] question about this: [Are questions about how to develop worldbuilding software on topic?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/511/29). Please make your case there. (My personal opinion remains that this type of question is off topic on this site.)

Comment: I think this one would work better in Programmers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A hierarchical triangulated irregular network (HTIN) is probably what you are after.

A TIN consists of a delauny triangulation over a set of point samples which are distributed based on the frequency of the surface being modelled. Where the surface varies rapidly, the points are dense, and where the surface does not vary, the points are sparse.

In a hierarchical TIN, the points and their triangulation incorporate an order of precedence and a spatial index so that sections of the triangulation can be extracted at specific levels of detail.

Comment: I'm afraid my familiarity with the specific details of HTIN algorithms is lacking so you'll have to do some digging through academic papers for details.  I've worked with some related algorithms for stipple generation but not HTINs themselves.

Answer (score 6):

There are two common ways to store elevation data, the first is by point the second is by contour.

Storing a selection of points suffers because you're limited by the granularity of your data, if you only hold an elevation each metre of surface area you have to interpolate the distance in between. You also end up with a lot of redundant data (after all large portions of land are effectively flat).

If you look at almost any good mountaineering map you'll notice that height is not indicated by a sequence of dots in a grid. It's represented by contours, these lines (of varying size and shape circles encircle peaks and mountains. As you can imagine it's a lot more efficient to store a line of coordinates which are at the same height than every point on the globe.

In terms of actual data structures I would suggest the following:

```
<contours>
  <contour height="123">
    <point lng="53.2852" lat="-3.5788" />
    <point lng="53.2952" lat="-3.5288" />
  </contour>
</contours>
```

When your application is passed a point it should determine which is the innermost contour it lies within (perhaps add a ParentContourID to help?). That will be the height of your point (or you can interpolate from the nearest two).

Comment: Now I'm grumpy, I was aiming for the Lake District with those coordinates, hit North Wales instead. Not bad from memory though!

Comment: Contours are used on maps because they are easy for humans to interpret, but they are quite hard to interpolate effectively.  That's why DEMs are based on points, either regular sets as raster DEMS, or irregular points in a TIN. In any any modern map with contours, those contours are going to be derived from point data of some sort.

Comment: @smithkm I was thinking more from a data storage perspective. Thanks for the additional information about HTINs - really interesting stuff!